# dynamic and Reflection

Tags: reflection, c#-4.0

I'd like to use Reflection in combination with dynamic.
Lets say i have the following call

`dynamic foo = External_COM_Api_Call()`

Accessing an object that i receive using COM.

Now I'd like to do somthing like that:

`String bar = foo.GetType().GetProperty("FooBar").GetValue(foo,null)`

But i keep getting a null for the PropertyInfo.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why using reflection when you could directly:

```
dynamic foo = External_COM_Api_Call();
string value = foo.FooBar;
```

That's the whole point of the `dynamic` keyword. You no longer need reflection.

And if you want to use reflection then don't use dynamic:

```
object foo = External_COM_Api_Call();
string bar = (string)foo
   .GetType()
   .InvokeMember("FooBar", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, foo, null);
```

---

Here's a full working example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WScript.Shell");
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var result = (string)type
            .InvokeMember("CurrentDirectory", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, instance, null);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: dynamic coding. I want to specify the property to access via (e.g.) a config file

Comment: @jaster, then you don't need dynamic, you need pure reflection. See my second example.

Comment: this won't work, since the provided type is a com type ;) i already wrote your example in my question post.

Comment: @Jaster, I've updated my answer to provide you with a working example using reflection.

Comment: Instresting; invokation works with dynamic + COM while property reflection does not. Thanks ;)